# Ansible winrm_server_cert_validation HTTPS security

Tags: powershell, ssl, https, ansible, winrm

I am using Ansible on a Linux computer connecting to a windows 8.1 embedded computer. It's able to connect with username and password over the HTTPS port 5986, but I need to specify the option:
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
The ansible documentation specifies:

> The following is necessary for Python 2.7.9+ (or any older Python that
>   has backported SSLContext, eg, Python 2.7.5 on RHEL7) when using
>   default WinRM self-signed certificates:

The windows computer has an SSL listener that was configured with Self-SignedCertificates from the powershell script:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1
My question is that if I'm ignoring server cert validation, does that compromise the encryption that HTTPS is supposed to provide? or is server cert validation just a separate process of HTTPS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you ignore certificate validation as recommended in the [default Ansible config for WinRM](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_windows.html#inventory), your connection is not secure - someone can spoof the target server using a man in the middle (MITM) attack on the HTTPS connection. (There should really be a security warning in the Ansible docs.)

The best alternative seems to be NTLM/Negotiate authentication, instead of HTTPS, removing the need for an SSL certificate.  Your Ansible control machine will need to be able to authenticate over NTLM as a Windows user, just like using an SMB file share.

You will need `pywinrm` [0.2.0 or higher](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/50#issuecomment-299943605) for NTLM/Negotiate support.

#### Useful links

- [Why NTLM/Negotiate for WinRM](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/sane-authenticationencryption-arrives-to-ruby-based-cross-platform-winrm-remote-execution) - background on why it's good to avoid the [complex setup to install SSL certificates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2019527/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https) by using NTLM (Ruby based but still useful)
- [Example Ansible setup for NTLM](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/50#issuecomment-236408691)
- [More complete Ansible setup including NTLM](https://aseemkblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/configuring-ansible-to-manage-windows-system-over-powershell/)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I figured ignoring the server cert validation would be a security risk and it is strange that Ansible doesn't document this more thoroughly. I might have missed where one of the articles state this, but does NTLM require an Active Directory service in order for this kind of authentication to take place?

Comment: Not sure about NTLM without Active Directory - it's best if you write a new question about that to attract Windows experts.

Answer (score 2):

Certificate validation is a separate process than encryption. The communication will be encrypted. You can read more on the [issues with self-signed certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/what-are-the-risks-of-self-signing-a-certificate-for-ssl) but the high level is you remove any way for Ansible to validate who exactly is on the other side of the connection an open your self to a man in the middle attack that HTTPS usually protects you from.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I'm understanding the link you sent me and what you said correctly, even though I'm ignoring the cert validation stage, the key exchange still happens in order for encryption to happen?

Comment: Yes, the encryption is still occurring.